# VectorSource() as import module - is it possible?

Tags: openlayers

How to achieve use VectorSource() as import module and pass layerUrl as parameter inside object?
e.g.

```
new VectorSource({format:  new GeoJSON(), loader: function(), my_layer_name: layerName})
```

I have many wfs layers and trying simplicity the code.
But have no idea how to pass my own parameter into OpenLayers object VectorSource({}).

Any tips are welcome.
It's a code snipped

```
    const layerName = "v_alarm_co";

    const vSource = new VectorSource({
          format: new GeoJSON(),
          loader: function(extent) {
            const layerUrl =
              "/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=" +
              layerName +
              "&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=" +
              extent.join(",") +
              ",EPSG:3857";
            xhr.open("GET", layerUrl, true);
            const onError = () => {
              vSource.removeLoadedExtent(extent);
            };
            xhr.onerror = onError;
            xhr.onload = () => {
              if (xhr.status == 200) {
                vSource.addFeatures(vSource.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText));
              } else {
                onError();
              }
            };
            xhr.send(null);
          },
          strategy: bbox
        });
```

Comment: You would need to sub-class the VectorSource constructor, or simply wrap it in a function for example https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-wfs-forked-kszpc?file=/main.js

Comment: Thanks for the answer!